# I cannot parse website (steamdb.info) using requests

Tags: python-3.x, parsing, beautifulsoup, python-requests, steam

Steamdb doesn't allow to parse itself, at least, using common ways. Python methods can only return a plug-site "Please stand by, we are checking your browser".

I've tried to get HTML-code of site using classic parser methods, requests.get with fake_useragent, though response of this method is plug-site.
[This is how main site looks like actually](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DoJlV.png)
[This is what I receive as respond of get method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hLIBF.png)

```
import requests as rq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import fake_useragent


#fake_useragent
user = fake_useragent.UserAgent().random
header = {"user-agent": user}
session = rq.Session()

link = "https://steamdb.info/"

resp = session.get(link, headers=header)
with open("steam.html","w",encoding='utf-8') as file:
    file.write(resp.text)
```

Comment: It seems the website that you mentioned is using Cloudflare service protection. i think the workaround is to get the actual HTML instead you can bypass it with this [cloudscraper](https://pypi.org/project/cloudscraper/)